# search logic is doing wrong search?

Tags: c#, search

We have problem with my search logic. when user want to search Area "team Area 123" it will search for first last names because of space. just want to see how can we told search it is not first last name search and you are doing the wrong one ?

```
public IEnumerable<User> Query()
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
    {
        int ext = 0;
        if (query.Contains("."))
        {
            return repository.SelectSearchByEmail(query.Trim());
        }
        else if (query.Contains(","))
        {
            var names = query.Split(',');
            var firstName  = names[0];
            var lastName = names[1];
            return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
        }
        else if (query.Contains(" "))
        {
            var names = query.Split(' ');
            var firstName = names[0];
            var lastName = names[1];
            return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
        }
        else if (query.Contains("_"))
        {
            var names = query.Split('_');
            var firstName = names[0];
            var lastName = names[1];
            return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
        }
        else if (int.TryParse(query, out ext))
        {
            return repository.SelectSearchByExt(ext);
        }
        else
        {
            return repository.SelectAllUserByQuery(query);
        }
    }
    return new List<User>();
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing to me, can you try explain your problem in other way?

Comment: Your question is not clear, what are you looking for help?

Comment: There's not really any way it can distinguish between a search entry that consists of someone's first and last name vs. an entry that is something else.  Computers are not good at that; the differences in meaning is discernible only to a human.

Comment: the user type "team Area 123" because of space it think I'm searching for First name , last name  because query search has space " "

Comment: And what *are* you searching for? You should provide a complete, working example including current outcome and *expected* outcome.

Comment: Tell the use not to type "team Area 123" ;-) But seriously: what should happen, for a search with "team Area 123"?

Comment: just want to ask can I use goto  to control my search work. like if I have  result  go to next search ?

Comment: @Alex give me result of list  users how work at Area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

Count the number of spaces in the string

```
// For brevity use.
int spacesCount = query.Count(f => f == ' ');

// For speed use.
int spacesCount = 0;

foreach (char c in query) 
{
    if (c == ' ')
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Only fall into the else if when there is 1 space, e.g. "firstname lastname"

So change

```
else if (query.Contains(" "))
```

to

```
else if (spacesCount == 1)
```

Your code should look like:

```
public IEnumerable<User> Query()
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
    {
        int ext = 0;
        int spacesCount = query.Count(f => f == ' ');

        if (query.Contains("."))
        {
            return repository.SelectSearchByEmail(query.Trim());
        }
        else if (query.Contains(","))
        {
            var names = query.Split(',');
            var firstName  = names[0];
            var lastName = names[1];
            return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
        }
        else if (spacesCount == 1)
        {
            var names = query.Split(' ');
            var firstName = names[0];
            var lastName = names[1];
            return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
        }
        else if (query.Contains("_"))
        {
            var names = query.Split('_');
            var firstName = names[0];
            var lastName = names[1];
            return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
        }
        else if (int.TryParse(query, out ext))
        {
            return repository.SelectSearchByExt(ext);
        }
        else
        {
            return repository.SelectAllUserByQuery(query);
        }
    }
    return new List<User>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a condition while checking for spaces :

```
public IEnumerable<User> Query()
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
    {
        int ext = 0;
        if (query.Contains("."))
        {
            return repository.SelectSearchByEmail(query.Trim());
        }
        else if (query.Contains(","))
        {
            var names = query.Split(',');
            var firstName  = names[0];
            var lastName = names[1];
            return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
        }
        else if (query.Contains(" ") && query.Split(" ").Length ==2 ) //This Line
        {
            var names = query.Split(' ');
            var firstName = names[0];
            var lastName = names[1];
            return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
        }
        else if (query.Contains("_"))
        {
            var names = query.Split('_');
            var firstName = names[0];
            var lastName = names[1];
            return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
        }
        else if (int.TryParse(query, out ext))
        {
            return repository.SelectSearchByExt(ext);
        }
        else
        {
            return repository.SelectAllUserByQuery(query);
        }
    }
    return new List<User>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well then you can do the following:

```
    public IEnumerable<User> Query()
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            int ext = 0;
            if (query.Contains("."))
            {
                return repository.SelectSearchByEmail(query.Trim());
            }
            else if (query.Contains(","))
            {
                var names = query.Split(',');
                var firstName  = names[0];
                var lastName = names[1];
                return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
            }
            else if (query.Contains(" ") && query.Split(" ").Length == 2)
            {
                var names = query.Split(' ');
                var firstName = names[0];
                var lastName = names[1];
                return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
            }
else if (query.Contains(" ") && query.Split(" ").Length == 3)
            {
                //display message wrong search pattern or search by area if you have such method
                var names = query.Split(' ');
                var firstName = names[0];
                var lastName = names[1];
                return repository.SelectSearchByArea(query.Split(" ")[1]);
            }
            else if (query.Contains("_"))
            {
                var names = query.Split('_');
                var firstName = names[0];
                var lastName = names[1];
                return repository.SelectSearchByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
            }
            else if (int.TryParse(query, out ext))
            {
                return repository.SelectSearchByExt(ext);
            }
            else
            {
                return repository.SelectAllUserByQuery(query);
            }
        }
        return new List<User>();
    }
```